# How to use grid widget in Drupalgap?

Tags: javascript

I cannot reproduce the grid widget. The page shows nothing except the title. Here is my code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu()
 */
function test_grid_menu() {
  var items = {};
  items['test_grid'] = {
    title:'test grid',
    page_callback: 'test_grid_page',
  };
  return items;
}


function test_grid_page() {

var content = {};
content['my_grid'] = {
  theme: 'jqm_grid',
  columns: 2,
  items: [
    bl('Foo', 'foo'),
    bl('Bar', 'bar'),
    bl('Baz', 'baz'),
    bl('Chop', 'chop')
  ]
};
return content;
}
```

I also tried to put the theme('jqm_grid', ...) in the page_callback, but it does not work.

```
function test_grid_page() {

var content = {};
content['my_grid'] = {
  theme: 'jqm_grid',
  columns: 2,
  items: [
    bl('Foo', 'foo'),
    bl('Bar', 'bar'),
    bl('Baz', 'baz'),
    bl('Chop', 'chop')
  ]
};
return content;

var html = theme('jqm_grid', {
  columns: 2,
  items: [
    bl('Foo', 'foo'),
    bl('Bar', 'bar'),
    bl('Baz', 'baz'),
    bl('Chop', 'chop')
  ]
});
return html;

}
```

I place the jQuery Block code in the page_callback. The page display is fine as expect, but the linking is a problem.(cannot reach the localhost node) It seems this can only give good display but without the function. (in my following code, search and the linking have no function).

```
function test_grid2_page() {

var  html = '<div><form><label for="search-1">Search:</label>';
     html += '<input type="search" name="search-1" id="search-1" value=""></form></div>';
     html += '<div class="ui-grid-b">';
     html += ' <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:90px"><a href="javascript:drupalgap_goto("node/966");">Foo</a></div></div>';
     html += ' <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:90px">Bar</div></div>';
     html += ' <div class="ui-block-c"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:90px">Baz</div></div>';
     html += ' <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:90px">Chop</div></div>';
     html += ' <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:90px">Computer</div></div>';
     html += ' <div class="ui-block-c"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:90px">Wine</div></div>';
     html += '</div>';
return html;
}
```

I have fixed the linking using l(...) and bl(...), but I would like my buttons fill all the grid. The name of the button also out of the range, so it just show partially. Here is the code and result:

```
var  html = '<div><form><label for="search-1">Search:</label>';
     html += '<input type="search" name="search-1" id="search-1" value=""></form></div>';
     html += '<div class="ui-grid-b">';
     html += ' <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:90px">';
     html += bl('Foo', 'node/966', {attributes:{'data-icon':'action'}});
     html += '</div></div>';
     html += ' <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:90px">';
     html += bl('Bar', 'node/1028', {attributes:{'data-icon':'action'}});
     html += '</div></div>';
     html += ' <div class="ui-block-c"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:90px">';
     html += bl('Baz', 'node/1021', {attributes:{'data-icon':'action'}});
     html += '</div></div>';
     html += ' <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:90px">';
     html += bl('Chop', 'node/1027', {attributes:{'data-icon':'action'}});
     html += '</div></div>';
     html += ' <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:90px">';
     html += bl('Computer', 'node/1021', {attributes:{'data-icon':'action'}});
     html += '</div></div>';
     html += ' <div class="ui-block-c"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:90px">';
     html += bl('Wine', 'node/1025', {attributes:{'data-icon':'action'}});
     html += '</div></div>';
     html += '</div>';
return html;
```

[image]

Comment: This is probably better suited for the GitHub for DrupalGap. At a glance this looks like a PHP question.

Comment: It's JS @Kevin but you might be right about it being better suited to the GitHub queue

Comment: Yeah that is what I meant - which is why I deleted my answer.

Comment: thanks you guys. After lots of experiments, I have found a way to do it by directly return the jQuery code in the page_callback.

Comment: FYI, drupal.stackexchange.com is a great place for DrupalGap related questions, in fact it's listed as one of the places to get support for DrupalGap. That being said, would you mind updating your question to include your solution, I'd like to see your workaround, and am curious why the code in your question isn't working, because it looks perfect. Perhaps download the latest `drupalgap.min.js` file...

Comment: thank you Tyler. I have put my solution and will try the latest drupalgap.min.js later today.

Comment: @tyler I meant it seemed like it might be JS problem territory rather than Drupal-centric. DrupalGap questions are of course very welcome here

Comment: the `drupalgap.min.js` I use is 7.0.2 and after checking signalpoint. It seems to be the latest one.

Comment: I guess the theme "jqm_grid" is not supported. Where can I find the information of all the available theme types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Tyler. I am giving more detail of the solution.

First download the new drupalgap.min.js from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/signalpoint/DrupalGap/7.x-1.x/bin/drupalgap.min.js
and place it in the bin directory.

Modified the `index.html` where originally `<!-- DrupalGap -->
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="bin/drupalgap-7.0.2.min.js"></script>` to the new `drupalgap.min.js`.

Then the grid widget from the drupalgap document http://docs.drupalgap.org/7/Widgets/Grid_Widget  starts to work! Both Render Array and theme('jqm_grid', ...) can successfully do it. Just pick one. The code below is using render array.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu()
 */
function test_grid2_menu() {
  var items = {};
  items['test_grid2'] = {
    title:'test grid2',
    page_callback: 'test_grid2_page',
  };
  return items;
}


function test_grid2_page() {

var content = {};
content['my_grid'] = {
  theme: 'jqm_grid',
  columns: 2,
  items: [
    bl('Foo', 'foo'),
    bl('Bar', 'bar'),
    bl('Bar', 'bar'),
    bl('Baz', 'baz'),
    bl('Chop', 'chop')
  ]
};
return content;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Clive, thank you for confirming, and for your efforts. @artphys, try the latest dev snapshot, `jqm_grid` is definitely supported: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/signalpoint/DrupalGap/7.x-1.x/bin/drupalgap.min.js

Comment: I replaced `bin/drupalgap.js` and `bin/drupalgap.min.js` with the new ones, the code using jqm_grid still does not work. So I tried to replace all the directory of mobile-app with new Drupalgap-7.x-1.x and keep my own `app/setting.js` and modules, I cannot even display the original dashboard. It only shows the picture of Drupalgap in the centre and nothing eles. Did I miss somethings?

Comment: I replaced `bin/drupalgap.min.js` with the new one, and modified `index.html` to '<!-- DrupalGap -->
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="bin/drupalgap.min.js"></script>'. The grid widget from the document starts to work! Thank you.